# Git (DVCS) Best Practice

Tags: git, github, dvcs, branch

I am new to Github and recently forked somebody's project to make my own changes. Now though I learn it's best practice to create each new feature or bug fix in a new branch. Up until now I was just editing in the Master.

How can I can create a new branch out of my Master, then replace my edited master with the upstream code repository once again?

Comment: Worth noting that your question is about Git not GitHub. Git is version control software Github is a site hosting Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the upstream repo is `origin`...

```
git branch some_feature
git reset origin/master
```

Now your branch is where the remote master branch is, and your code is on the branch `some_feature`.